# IIS Intranet Application accessed by two different local networks

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, dns

Got stuck in a very strange situation. I am a developer so really not very good in networking. I really need help to figure out the solution if my problem. So, here is my problem,

I am working on intranet application in ASP.NET and it is hosted on IIS. This application is using Windows Authentication. We have two offices on different location of our company. This application is running absolutely fine in the office where I am working. But the problem is it is not working in our other office.

I have checked that we are in a same domain but in different networks. Domain is same so windows authentication should work but the application is not accessible in other office. I want my application to be accessible by that office also.

What should I need to do to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean "not accessible"? I have a feeling that all your talk about Windows Authentication is a red herring. It sounds like your issue has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Firewall rules might be blocking your requests. Turn on IIS logging to see if the request even reaches your webserver. Then turn off firewall/proxy etc to see if it reaches. Also, many times diff subnets are configured to be isolated from each other, so you may have to contact your networking team to allow communication across them.

Comment: @mason: I mean people in the other office are not able to open that application in their web browsers.

Comment: @Mrchief: So I need to test it by turning firewall off at the another office, right? Just want to make sure?

Comment: @Rebecca You need to describe better than just "not able to open". Are they getting an error message? If you watch the network traffic in the browser's development tools, do the requests reach the server? Does the DNS resolve the hostname/domain name to an IP address?

Comment: @mason I am sorry about that. I am new to this. From next time I will make sure to include all necessary details.

Comment: @mason: They are only getting this error message: "This page can't be displayed"  in all the browsers. and yest the DNS resolves the hostname/domain name to an IP address

Comment: @Rebecca Look at the network traffic in the browser's development tools (F12). You can watch the individual HTTP requests there. What is the status code of the requests to the site?

Comment: @mason: I am able to open that application here successfully. So I am not  seeing any HTTP requests to the site in my developer tool.

Comment: @Rebecca You need to look at the browser running at the location that's having trouble accessing the site, and watch the traffic on that browser's development tools.

Comment: @mason: Ok, I will figure out that and will post that information here.

Comment: @mason: server is not returning anything there. No status code.No requests.

Comment: There HAS to be a request, if you open the browser's dev tools and accessing the networking info, then make a request to your web server.

Comment: @mason: No, the server is not returning anything.Is it because of the firewall? because there is one other application on different port which is running in that office.

Comment: The server not returning anything would mean there is no **response**. There would still be a **request**. And yes, if your firewall is blocking communication on the port the app is on, you will need to configure the firewall to allow access to that port. An alternative is to host all your web applications on a single site, split into multiple virtual applications. Then you only need one port (Typically 80 for HTTP, or 443 for HTTPS, or both).

Comment: Sounds great mason. Splitting an application on a single site is a great idea. Thank you for all your help. I will also contact my network admin to see if its a firewall issue. Thanks again:)

Comment: @mason: Mason, I checked with the Network Admin but it is not firewall issue. I also split one site into application but that doesn't resolve the problem. What should I do now?

Comment: Like I've been saying, you need to watch the request in the browser's networking tools and see why the request fails. You need the exact error message.

Comment: @mason: I saw the request it only has Request URL description i.e. name of the URL that's it.

Comment: There will be more than that. If the request fails, it will say that in your browser's dev tools.

Comment: @mason: Hi mason, you were right, it was some firewall issue. The issue has been solved. Thank you for your help.:)